# Programmatic registering an ActiveX control

Tags: visual-studio-2008, com, visual-studio-2005, activex

I have an ActiveX control that I developed in VS2005.  I've converted it over to VS2008.  I have a ComRegisterFunctionAttribute and a ComUnregisterFunctionAttribute in my code, and all works well when I compile and debug on my XP system at work.  When I try to run it on my Vista laptop at home, I get the following error:

"Cannot register assembly "D:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008 Projects\C#\BLINCodes\BLINCodes\bin\Debug\BLINCodes.dll" - access denied.  Please make sure that you're running the application as administrator.  Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\RTPS.BLINCodes' is denied."

I understand that with the newer 64 bit operating systems, you have to run as administrator to register the dlls, but can I do it programmatically the way I've been doing?  Here's the code:

```
    [ComRegisterFunctionAttribute]
    public static void RegisterFunction(Type t)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(@"CLSID\{" + t.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() + @"}\Programmable");
        Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(@"CLSID\{" + t.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() + @"}\Control");

        string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(BLINCodes)).Location;
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey subkey;
        subkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(@"CLSID\{" + t.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() + @"}\DefaultIcon");
        subkey.SetValue("", path + ",102");
        subkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(@"CLSID\{" + t.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() + @"}\ToolBoxBitmap32");
        subkey.SetValue("", path + ",102");
    }

    [ComUnregisterFunctionAttribute]
    public static void UnregisterFunction(Type t)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKey(@"CLSID\{" + t.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() + @"}\Programmable");
        Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKey(@"CLSID\{" + t.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() + @"}\Control");
        Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKey(@"CLSID\{" + t.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() + @"}\ToolBoxBitmap32");
        Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKey(@"CLSID\{" + t.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() + @"}\DefaultIcon");
    }
```

Thanks for any an all help.

MM

Comment: No, that requires a manifest in the tool that registers your assembly that asks for admin rights to trigger the UAC prompt.  Which is Regasm.exe, Microsoft didn't do that.  You are forgetting to write some necessary registry entries btw.